# TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'CreateObjectURL' Of Undefined

Tags: angular, angular-universal, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

We have an angular app and I'm trying to implement Server-Side Rendering(SSR) to our existing `Angular` Application for SEO & Link Preview:

`Angular Version: 8.2.3`

Steps I have performed to convert it to `SSR`:

1. Adding `Angular` Universal using Angular CLI

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject {{ name of your project }}`

2. Build Commands I'm using

`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

3. window object & other polyfills I have added in server.ts using domino

```
import fs from 'fs';
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html')).toString();
import { Blob } from "blob-polyfill";

const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global["object"] = win.object;
global["HTMLElement"] = win.HTMLElement;
global["navigator"] = win.navigator;
global['Blob'] = Blob;

/** NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack */
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

/** Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine) */
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
```

I tried to check if it is any 3rd party package, if it is causing the error, I could understand that it is `aws-aplify-angular`, inside it, there is `aws-lex-audio.js` which contains that line which is causing that error. And even I am not using the `interactions module` which contains that file. But still no luck.

The solution I tried,

I tried to use the amplify modular approach to exclude *interactions* module if it helps

```
    {
        provide: AmplifyService,
        useFactory:  () => {
          return AmplifyModules({
            Auth,
            Storage,
          });
        }
    },
]
```

Is there any way to get rid of this error?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, I have the same issue man. Trying to fix it now.

Comment: @Veslav Did you fixed it?

Comment: @BecarioSenior yes, the solution below worked for me, my site royhonders.com is now online.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using `aws-amplify-angular` and you imported it somewhere in your modules.

This will also import the interactions module, even though you don't need to use it. Just make sure not to use this module and you will be fine.

Comment: Same issue here. I removed all Amplify deps from the project and started again step by step. This problem appears just when AngularAmplifyModule is placed in AppModule. Factory load of AmplifyService have no effect on it. Still got no solution.
aws-amplify-angular": "^4.1.2"

Comment: Besides the error mentioned by the op, this file aws-lex-audio.js decreases the performance of the download (server processing) dramatically. I suspect aws-amplify-angular is not compatible with angular-universal despite the official documentation says nothing about that.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3115

Comment: @BecarioSenior I completely argree with both statements. Making sure that  AngularAmplifyModule removed from AppModule will fix OP's issue. It does suck though that it's not really compatible with angular-universal.